# cakePHP Many to Many relationship - load table records inside view that has nothing to do with the relation

Tags: php, cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-model

I have an editions, videos table. An edition can have many videos.

A video has many players and a player has many videos. So there is a Many to Many relationship between videos and players.

In my editions view I load all the videos related to that edition. But I also want to load the players information that belongs to a video. In the database there is no relationship between editions and players, because that relationship is between videos and players (many to many - players_videos).

I'm able to load the players_id's related to a video. I get those id's out of the players_videos table.

How do I load the players information that belongs to a video inside the edition view?

Edition model has many relationship:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Video' => array(
        'className' => 'Video',
        'foreignKey' => 'edition_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
);
```

EditionsController view action :

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Edition->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid edition'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Edition.' . $this->Edition->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('edition', $this->Edition->find('first', $options));

    $tab = array('Video.' . $this->Video->primaryKey => $id); // which you loop for the video list and fill with their ids
    $playersvideos = $this->Edition->Video->PlayersVideo->find('all', array('conditions' => array('PlayersVideo.video_id' => $tab),'recursive'=>2));
    $this->set('playersvideos ', $playersvideos);
}
```

view.ctp :

```
<?php foreach ($edition['Video'] as $video): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $video['video_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $video['video_title']; ?></td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>
            <?php foreach ($playersvideos as $playervideo): ?>
                    <?php echo $playervideo['PlayersVideo']['player_id']; ?>
                    <?php echo $playervideo['PlayersVideo']['video_id']; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Players has and belongs to many relationship :

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Video' => array(
        'className' => 'Video',
        'joinTable' => 'players_videos',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'video_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

Video has and belongs to many relationship :

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Player' => array(
        'className' => 'Player',
        'joinTable' => 'players_videos',
        'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'player_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    )
);
```

PlayersVideo belongs to relationship

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Video' => array(
        'className' => 'Video',
        'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
    ),
    'Player' => array(
        'className' => 'Player',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok , here how i do it :
in the controller , for example in the function edit :

```
public function edit($id = null){
....

$tab = array(); // which you loop for the video list and fill with their ids
$players= $this->Edition->Video->Player->find('all',array(
                                'conditions' => array('Player.video_id IN ' => $tab),'recursive'=>2));
$this->set('player',$players);
}
```

in your edit.ctp , you loop for it and show it as you want.hope it helps

Comment: plz delete the IN from the query : $players= $this->Edition->Video->Player->find('all',array(
                                'conditions' => array('Player.video_id ' => $tab),'recursive'=>2));

Comment: actually yeah , you're right. listen the idea is to retrieve the players how have the video_id in the $tab.

Comment: $players= $this->Player->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Player.video_id' => $tab),'recursive'=>2));

Comment: you have set ('player',$players) so you access to $player normally like the others : foreach($player as $play): echo $player['Player']['column_name']; endforeach;

Comment: I deleted my comments and updated my question again, hope someone has an answer.